# Using Spring Framework, update folder mapping after a creation of a new one

Tags: java, spring, mapping, directory

my application uses Spring Framework and it manages upload of images. For each image, i would create a folder:

```
->webSite ->images/
                 ->img1/img1.jpg
                 ->img2/img2.jpg
after a new upload i will have
->webSite ->images/
                 ->img1/img1.jpg
                 ->img2/img2.jpg
                 ->img3/img3.jpg
```

Unfortunately, when i deployed the program, all images are immediatly reachable, but after an upload, the new one isn't it.(in the previous example, img1/img1.jpg ok, img2/img2.jpg ok but img3/img3.jpg error 404 )

If i deploy again, the image img3.jpg now is available.

Anyone know how refresh in runtime the folder's mapping?

To map the initial folder images i set only the web.xml with:

```
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use special spring configuration for resources instead of special serlvet:

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

put this line to your servlet-context.xml